# How do I make a sprite "jump", in a simple Mario-like game?

Tags: python, pygame

What would be the best way to cause the spriteimg jump. I want to have the sprite glide up and then back down when K_UP is pressed. What would be the best approach to this?

```
while running:
    setup_background()
    spriteimg = plumberright

    screen.blit(spriteimg,(x1, y1))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
              y1 -= 2
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
              x1 += 2
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
               x1 -= 2


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you model the movement of your character as a velocity vector. The keys accelerate in a certain direction. Gravity and friction (and collisions) bring the player to stop.

I found this here (it's not python but the ideas are the same), maybe it helps: http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/

Comment: You could also save the sequence of jump movements as a list and iterate through the movements in the list. Not as flexible, but another option.

Answer (score 1):

My cohort covered this during our tutorial at PyCon this year:

http://pyvideo.org/video/615/introduction-to-game-development

You'll want to start at 31:00 if you don't want to listen me to talk about game design :)